# Cache is breaking HTML table when refreshing page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've been battling with this issue for a while now and can't find out why it's happening. I basically have a table which displays Woocommerce variations with each variation being in it's own row. The problem I have is when refreshing the page, the `<th>` row collapses and doesn't line up with the `tbody`.

Interestingly, if i change some of the css of the `<th>` in the console after the page loads, it fixes itself and lines up. The same applies If i open up the console after turn on 'Disable Cache' in the network tab and refresh the page.

My guess is the html is being loaded before the Woocommerce data is being added and doesn't have enough time to get the correct widths. However, this is a recent issue which has only just started happening.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

```
<table class="variations variations-grid" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><img class="camera-icon" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/picture-holder.png"></th>
         <th>
            Type
         </th>
         <th>Length</th>
         <th class="length">Weight</th>
         <th>Height</th>
         <th>Depth</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div class="thumbnail">
               <img width="44" height="54" alt="Photinia Red Robin " src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Photinia-Red-Robin-267x325.jpg">
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="attr attr-attribute_size">
            <p>Hedge Bag</p>
         </td>
         <td class="attr attr-attribute_length">
            <p>100cm</p>
         </td>
         <td class="attr attr-attribute_weight">
            <p>75Kg</p>
         </td>
         <td class="attr attr-attribute_height">
            <p>140-150cm+</p>
         </td>
         <td class="attr attr-attribute_depth">
            <p>40cm</p>
         </td>
         <td class="price">
            <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>191.00</span></span>                    
            per metre                
         </td>
         <td class="product-actions">
            <a class="button" href="#modal0">More info</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what is looks like broken: 
[image]

This is what is looks like if i the disable cache OR change the css once it's loaded. This is how It should look.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I count more `<td>` in your `<tbody>` than `<th>` in your `<thead>`. Could this be the issue? Try to add empty `<td>` to match your `<th>` head count to test.

Comment: I tried adding empty '<th>' to the thead but the problem still exists.